# Is this function able to change the values of a dict?

Tags: python, graph, networkx, dijkstra

```
import networkx as nx

def function_x(G)
  distances = nx.all_pairs_dijkstra_path_length(G, weight='weight')
  count = 0
  for u, ud in distances:
    for v, d in ud.items():
      if G.has_edge(u, v):
        if G.edges[u, v]['weight'] > d:
          count += 1
          G.edges[u, v]['weight'] = d
  return count
```

Obviously G stands for a graph with positive weights.

Given that this algorithm can change the weights of some edges, is it possible that the distances that have been calculated by the function `all_pairs_dijkstra_path_length()` to change when `function_x()` exits?

Comment: You're asking if changing `G` will change elements in `distances`?

Comment: For instance if distances has the values 10, 20 and 50, is it possible that after compiling, distances to have different values due to the code in the loops?